# Can I ask for exercise ideas?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask a question requesting ideas for tuning exercises, particularly in concert bands (although I suspect they'd apply to any band that uses wind or string instruments).

I can formulate a question easily enough, but there's unlikely to be single canonical answer that is right. I'd intend to answer it myself with the ideas I've used, and hope others can contribute different ideas.

Would this be a valid ontopic question?

Comment: You can float it and see what happens, the most you'll loose are some fake internet points.

Comment: However, "I'd intend to answer it myself with the ideas I've used, and hope others can contribute different ideas." makes me think that you want a list type question.

Comment: @Dave I was leaning in that direction, but then I wasn't sure, so I decided to ask. I do think it's a valuable question, which can have multiple useful answers, but I'm not sure it fits here. In the absence of other feedback, I might give it a go in a few days.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm sure you've seen, the ["on topic" page](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states that it is *on* topic to:

> ask a question about ... practice or performance technique.

The same page states that it's *off* topic to ask about:

> recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play.

At first glance, it sounds like your question straddles the line between these two, but after some reflection, I think your question is on topic, because I think your question is more along the lines of "how do I improve my tuning" than "which exercise is best?" The first question ("How do I improve my tuning") is about playing in tune, which is a practice or performance technique. Additionally, this seems like the sort of question that would solicit high quality answers from experts who have a lot of experience working on their tuning. And expert participation is what the site wants. So perhaps you could phrase your question something like this: "I play french horn in a concert band and occasionally am not as in tune as I would like to be. How can I improve my tuning? Are there exercises that help, and if so, what are some examples of these? Are there specific things to look for in my breathing, etc. which cause out-of-tune playing?" Maybe this is too many questions for one post, but based on other stackexchange sites, I think it would be appropriate.

EDIT: [here's a music.se question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45680/whats-the-best-exercise-to-master-2-5-1-or-cycle-of-5ths-on-a-chromatic-accordi) that reminds me a lot of your proposed question. This existing question hasn't gotten any flack.

Comment: [Here's a similar music.se question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45680/whats-the-best-exercise-to-master-2-5-1-or-cycle-of-5ths-on-a-chromatic-accordi) that reminds me a lot of your proposed question. This existing question hasn't gotten any flack for being off topic. In fact, that question was bumped to the homepage. I say "ask away"!

Comment: Thanks for your research effort, and thoughts. I'll stick something together in the next couple of days.